# Datagrid update ItemRenderer with ItemEditor value

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I have a datagrid with ItemRenderer and ItemEditor.
On click, as my datagrid is editable, I could modify the value of editing cell.
But, when, I valid those change, with tab key, for exemple, itemrender value is the same that at the beginning, no change appear.

Can you explain to me how to solve that?

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="scRub2" headerText="{sNomCol2}" 
editable="true" width="{iNomCol2}"id="dgc1" wordWrap="true"
                                                                itemRenderer="itemRenderer.MultilineHTMLRenderer"
itemEditor="itemRenderer.irHtmlText"
editorDataField="htmlModif"
```

// itemEditor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        public var htmlModif:String;
        protected function lblData_changeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            htmlModif = lblData.htmlText;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<mx:TextArea id="lblData" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0"     
             htmlText="{dataGridListData.label}"  preinitialize="initTA()"
             change="lblData_changeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import flash.events.Event;

            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;

            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
            import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;
            [Bindable("dataChange")] private var _listData : BaseListData;

            override public function get listData():BaseListData
            {
                return _listData;            
            }                   
            override public function set listData( value : BaseListData ) : void
            {
                _listData = value;
            }

            private function onChange(event:Event):void
            {
                this.data[ (listData as DataGridListData).dataField ] = lblData.htmlText;
            }
            public function initTA():void {         
                addEventListener("dataChange", handleDataChanged);
            }   

            public function handleDataChanged(event:Event):void {       
                // Cast listData to DataGridListData. 
                var myListData:DataGridListData = 
                    DataGridListData(listData);
                // Access information about the data passed 
                // to the cell renderer.
                trace("row index: " + String(myListData.rowIndex) + 
                    " column index: " + String(myListData.columnIndex));

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</mx:TextArea>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didnt run your code but thinks changing field **htmlModif** into **get** function will solves your problem

```
public var htmlModif:String;
        protected function lblData_changeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            htmlModif = lblData.htmlText;
        }
```

to

```
    public function get htmlModif():String
    {
        return lblData.htmlText;
    }
```

Hopes that helps